# Extracting difference between 2 images in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, webcam, video-processing, aforge

I am using webcamera in C# (using AForge). I also have some default background. I need to extract the difference between current image and background and create a new image which contains only the objects which are not present on the default background. For example, if I move my hand in front of webcamera, I need to output only that hand (with the rest of backgound white). If I just compare pixel by pixel it gets ugly, since there is a lot of noise. I have tried using threshold value for difference, but the result is still very bad. I think that maybe there is some filter or a known algorithm how to do that? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Just a thought, can't you use the Kinect SDK? http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/kinectsdk/ Or maybe this will at least give you a clue how to solve your problem.

Comment: Isn't this SDK for Kinect device? At least it says so in the SDK description. I am using only single webcam. Actually I have found a filter in AForge, called CustomFrameDifferenceDetector Class, but there is not enough documentation on how to use it. At least I couldn't find it yet.

Comment: Don't know for sure. Just thought about it when you wanted to track hand movements.. :)

Comment: Check out this. Maybe it can help. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greg_schechter/archive/2008/09/16/introducing-multi-input-shader-effects.aspx

Comment: And using the helper class in that thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769863/how-to-get-bitmapimage-bytes-after-applying-image-effect you can extract the new image with ps effect applied.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to compare the grayscale images of the two. Assuming that your webcam is stationary (because if not, then you would have to do much more adjusting to pixel shifts), then you can convert the images to grayscale, and have a threshold by which you think the images differ:

```
int threshold = 30;
PixAvg1[i,j] = (Pix1.R + Pix1.G + Pix1.B)/3
PixAvg2[i,j] = (Pix2.R + Pix2.G + Pix2.B)/3
if (Math.Abs(PixAvg1[i,j] - PixAvg2[i,j+1])>threshold)
    difPixel == true;
```

The threshold is how much tolerance between the pixels you want to get. That value can come from the difference in brightness of the images.

With this you won't get the crispiest results, because some pixels you cover will match, however, you can then run an extra scan (if you want), and doing some kind of an area fill.